# "import xxx" not working on jupyter notebook but working on command prompt

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, libraries

I am trying to do "import pymongo" on jupyter-notebook, but then got the "No module named pymongo" error. But when I do "import pymongo" on pyspark shell, it works fine.

I am using jupyter notebook on remote server.

My bash_profile looks like this:

```
  # .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=/opt/app/anaconda2/python27/bin/python2.7:$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
export MASTER="yarn"
export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/app/anaconda2/python27/bin/python2.7
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/opt/app/anaconda2/python27/bin/python2.7
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/app/anaconda2/python27/bin/python2.7:$PYTHONPATH
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/opt/data/share05/sandbox/sandbox327/ly826p/sparklocaldir/
```

And my .bashrc looks like this:

```
# .bashrc
 
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
 
# User specific aliases and functions
 
##
# Java
##
 
# You need to make sure java 1.8 used for H2O work
 
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/app/java/jdk/jdk180
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
 
 
##
# Python Anaconda
##
 
# This is where we force Linux to use your local install of Anaconda
# CHANGE THESE PATHS to match your sestup
#ANACONDA2_LOC=/opt/app/anaconda2/python27/bin/
ANACONDA2_LOC=/opt/data/share05/sandbox/sandbox327/ly826p/anaconda_installs/bin
ANACONDA2_PYTHON=${ANACONDA2_LOC}/ipython
export PATH="$ANACONDA2_LOC:$PATH"
```

I am wondering if it's because I am using different python for jupyter notebook and command prompt?

Would like to know how to solve the issue and let pymongo work on my jupyternotebook.

Comment: _I am wondering if it's because I am using different python for jupyter notebook and command prompt?_ Yes, most likely. As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/. Also, did you manually edit the .bashrc and .bash_profile to set up Anaconda/Conda?

Comment: @AMC Thanks for the suggestion. I have edit the question. And also yes, I did manually edit those two files